# .NET Timer Service without SQL

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-services

I am writing a .NET Windows Service whose job is to monitor the status of documents stored in a document database (MongoDB).  These documents will be modified from time-to-time by users via a web site.  The Windows Service needs to run every, say, 5 minutes, poll around all the documents (hundreds of these), examine the documents and see if any of the documents needs attention from a user (a real person).  Users will be notified of required action via email.

The service will run 24/7.  There is no current SQL database in the mix, and I don't really want the overhead and expense of maintaining a SQL database just to support this requirement.  I do have MSMQ in the mix, alongside MongoDB.  I would consider using WWF, but is there a lightweight workflow persistence store that does not rely upon SQL?

Can anyone advise as to the best strategy to support this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can easily write your own implementation of persistence for workflows, I would suggest you to store data in XML file.
You can find the example of implementation of XML persistence here: [XML Instance Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Not sure how many workflows will be started in you case. If the number is big enough it might makes sence to use SQL Server because the approach with XML file can lead to concurrency and performance problems.